# Javascript: Can't stop the setTimeout

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

I'm working on a proxy server checker and have the following code to start the requests at intervals of roughly 5 seconds using the setTimeout function;

```
        function check() {

            var url = document.getElementById('url').value;
            var proxys = document.getElementById('proxys').value.replace(/\n/g,',');

            var proxys = proxys.split(",");

            for (proxy in proxys) {

                var proxytimeout = proxy*5000;

                t = setTimeout(doRequest, proxytimeout, url, proxys[proxy]);

            }
        }
```

However I can't stop them once their started!

```
        function stopcheck() {

            clearTimeout(t);

        }
```

A fix or better method will be more that appreciated.

Thank you Stack Overflow Community!

Comment: Are you sure that you actually call `stopcheck()` and check if you have defined `t` globally?

Comment: As an update; The function does stop the last settimeout.

Comment: Ben, you're overwriting the `t` reference. Only your last `setTimeout` will actually be referenced by `t`.

Comment: There are a couple of other issues with that code; I've updated my answer to call them out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 major problems with your code:

1. `t` is overwritten for each timeout, losing the reference to the previous timeout each iteration.
2. `t` is may not be a global variable, thus `stopcheck()` might not be able to "see" `t`.

Updated functions:

```
function check() {
    var url         = document.getElementById('url').value;
    var proxys      = document.getElementById('proxys').value.replace(/\n/g,',');
    var timeouts    = [];
    var index;
    var proxytimeout;

    proxys = proxys.split(",");
    for (index = 0; index < proxys.length; ++index) {
        proxytimeout                = index * 5000;
        timeouts[timeouts.length]   = setTimeout(
            doRequest, proxytimeout, url, proxys[index];
        );
    }

    return timeouts;
}

function stopcheck(timeouts) {
    for (var i = 0; i < timeouts.length; i++) {        
        clearTimeout(timeouts[i]);
    }
}
```

Example of use:

```
var timeouts = check();

// do some other stuff...

stopcheck(timeouts);
```

Comment: `t` *was* a global variable, as far as we could tell from his posted code. it wasn't declared in either function, meaning either it was declared globally, or it wasn't. In the latter case, it would become an implicit property of `window` (e.g., an implicit global, horrible though those are). Your approach is, of course, better than that.

Answer (score 3):

Where is 't' being defined?
It keeps being redefined in the for loop, so you will loose track of each timeout handle...

You could keep an array of handles:

```
var aTimeoutHandles = new Array();
var iCount = 0;
for (proxy in proxys) {

    var proxytimeout = proxy*5000;

    aTimeoutHandles[iCount++] = setTimeout(doRequest, proxytimeout, url, proxys[proxy]);

}
```

Comment: If you're setting multiple timeouts you'll need to keep track of each one, the way you're currently doing it every handle for a timeout is getting nuked when every new timer is created.  Also be sure to define your handles array in a scope where both functions can see.

Comment: Oh - can you not create multiple timeouts like that? I'm sure I've done that before somewhere!
Re: array - Sure - I was just demonstrating that you could store the timeout handles in an array. I guess I should have mentioned that the scope of the variable was important...

Comment: @Cryo: Your comment is correct for the OP's question, but Robert's answer stores the handles in an array.

Answer (score 2):

Define `t` outside of both functions first. Additionally, you're overwriting `t` with each iteration your `for` loop. Perhaps building a collection of references, and then to stop them you cycle through and `clearTimeout` on each.

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite `t` each time you set the interval. Thus you only end up clearing the last one set.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems there:

1. The main one is that you're overwriting `t` on each iteration of your `for` loop; you need an array of `t`s for your structure to work.
2. You're using `for..in` to loop through the indexes of the array. That's not what `for..in` is for (although there are a *lot* of people confused about that; [see this article](http://proto-scripty.wikidot.com/prototype:tip-looping-through-arrays)). `for..in` loops through the *property names of an object*, not the *indexes of an array*, and therefore this usage breaks in non-trivial situations. Just use an old-fashioned `for` loop.
3. You're declaring `proxys` twice. This is actually harmless, but...
4. You're not declaring `proxy` at all (which isn't harmless; it becomes an implicit global).

I've updated the code in Jordan's excellent answer to address those.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're setting multiple timeouts (one for each proxy), but trying to save them in the same variable.  You probably need to use an array there, instead of a simple variable.