# Trigger the event mouseenter only after specific time,

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, mouseenter

I have to call a function which is trigger by `mouseenter` event on specific element.

How can I trigger the `mouseenter` event only if the mouse "stands" more than 5 sec on the specific element?

Comment: Different event same problem/solution: [jQuery .keyup() delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/jquery-keyup-delay)

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060601/javascript-cant-stop-the-settimeout

Answer (score 3):

You can use a timer(setTimeout()) to schedule a function after 5 seconds, if the mouse leaves before that then we can clear the timer so that it won't be invoked.

```js
var timer;
$('#me').hover(function() {
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    snippet.log('called after 5000')
  }, 5000);
}, function() {
  //if leaves early then clear the timer
  clearTimeout(timer);
})
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Some text
<div id="me">hover me for more time</div>
more content
```

Comment: can I user mouseenter instead?